# How to make a python input work in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, input

I created this simple script called `txt.py`, which ask the user a txt with an input and write it into a txt file (it works):

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
txt = input('Text : ')
f.write(txt)
f.close()
```

The problem I encounter is that I have to use this script into a function in another python script called for example `test.py`. I'm calling the first one into the second with :

```
def myfunction():
    # some code
    os.system("python txt.py 1")
```

And this doesn't work as expected, my text file is edited but empty because the input field in the console doesn't show.

I also tried `subprocess.run(["python", 'txt.py'])` and get the same result.

Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `os.system` or  `subprocess.run`. You can create a function with all your `txt.py` code and simply call it on `myfunction()`. If you really need all this code in different files, just import the new function created in `txt.py` into `myfunction()`:

`txt.py` file:

```
def input_text():
    f = open('text.txt', 'a')
    txt = input('text : ')
    f.write(txt)
    f.close
```

`test.py` file:

```
from txt import input_text

def another_function():
    input_text()

another_function()
```

When you call `test.py` it will work just fine.

Ob.: I'm assuming your files are in the same directory, that's why I used `from txt import input_text`

I would like to suggest using `f.write(f'{txt}\n)` when writing the input text to your `text.txt` file to put each input in one line.

Finally, I created a reproducible example of this code [in one of my github repo](https://github.com/gabrielbdornas/stackoverflow-anwsers-reprex/tree/how-to-make-a-python-input-work-in-a-function). Feel free to use it whatever you want!